# Multiple Criteria in Filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way I can do multiple criteria inside filter function?

[image]

In the picture above, I only want to filter Column D (From Table 1) the duration of their calls ONLY and that would show on Table 2. The problem is that there are other data or value (random characters sometimes) in that single cell in Column D which you can see is row merged (In Table 1), I wanted to exclude everything inside except for the duration which is highlighted in yellow so I can make everything unmerged and final output will show in Table 2. Is this possible in Filter function?

Current Formula I'm using in Cell I3

```
=HSTACK(A3:A23,B3:B23,C3:C23,D3:D23,F3:F23)
```

Comment: From the look of it, why not filter column F instead? Otherwise `=FILTER (D3:D23,ISNUMBER(D3:D23))`

Comment: @P.b Table 1 is dynamic and it changes it's formatting and data every time. Its source is from a webpage so filtering it every time I refresh that table would be time consuming. I will try your formula in a few thank you!

Comment: What is the expected result? 3 or 15 rows?

Comment: should be 15 @VBasic2008

Comment: The Table 1 has 15 count of agents but consumes 23 rows because of the merged cells. I wanted to fix that. So in Table 2, it should come up with the clean version of Table 1 which should only have 15 rows, 15 agents, 15 status, removing the words "Everyone" and Phone Numbers in Column D, and keeping the rest @VBasic2008

Comment: Do you mean `=DROP(REDUCE(0,D3:D23,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(y,CHAR(10)),,-1)))),1)`?

Comment: @P.b From the picture of Table 1, imagine removing the merged cells by removing the value "Everyone" and the Phone Number from Column D. My table then should look clean and only have 15 rows instead of that Table 1 that has 15 count of agents but consumed 23 rows because of multiple values in Column D - which from there I only need the value of Duration.

Comment: Oh wait, column D is not merged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use this formula to 'extract' the values that are time.

```
=TEXT(FILTER(D3:D23,IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(D3:D23,"[h]:mm:ss")),"")<1),"[h]:mm:ss")
```

`TIMEVALUE` will return a `#VALUE` if the cell is not of time formatting. Taking advantage of this will allow you to ignore all non-time cells.

If you are attempting to retain the row position then this should work as a whole:

```
=HSTACK(A3:A23,B3:B23,C3:C23,TEXT(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(D3:D23,"[h]:mm:ss")),""),"[h]:mm:ss"),F3:F23)
```

**COMMENT UPDATE**

I think this should work for filtering out all data where Column D does not have a time format or include a `-`.

```
=HSTACK(FILTER(A3:C23,A3:A23<>0),FILTER(D3:D23,(D3:D23="-")+(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(D3:D23,"[h]:mm:ss")),0)>0)))
```

Comment: The first formula is exactly what I am looking for, however, I want that formula to include everything in the Table 1 like the column for Name, Status, Time in Status. My actual goal is to clean up Table 1 and exclude all values in Column D and only retain the value of the duration, and again, keeping all other value intact. Column D is a pain in the head because it can have multiple value, and I only really want to keep the duration so I would know how long the agent is currently talking on the phone.

Comment: and by the way, the Column F is just a helper column that I made. It is not that very reliable so I would have to remove that soon when I get this formula working.

Comment: So you want to only show Table 1 where there is a time value in column D? In the provided image it would be Table #, Headers, then 3 rows, excluding all other parts of the table?

Comment: Check out the update, just adjust the range to A:E once after `FILTER` when you want to exclude F.

Comment: Hello, I am really sorry for the confusion. Basically, I want a clean version of Table 1 where there is only a single ROW for everyone. The reason why there is a merged row for Column A (for the names) is because Column D has multiple values in it, and I want to fix that issue. I wanted to clean Column D by removing the ROW for the word "Everyone" and the phone number and only keep the duration OR the character "-" just in case the agent on column A status is OFFLINE/Available (which you can see on Column B). So Yes, I would still want to keep all other agents that has no call and no duration

Comment: As you can see on the picture I posted, on the Table 2, I highlighted the duration in YELLOW. So basically from that picture, I wanted to show Agent 3, Agent 12, and Agent 15 ONLY the duration, and remove the word "Everyone" and the Phone Number. The rest on the table should be intact because I still wanted to see all other agents statuses at the same time.

Comment: I'm going to check that right now. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I understand now, this may be an issue because when dealing with merged cells only the top left cell contains the actual value and the remaining merged cells indicate a value of 0. I assume the merged cells are automatically done and not performed by you? This may be difficult to resolve due to that. Will all rows be either 1 row or 3 rows for each person? That might help when trying to get all values in 1 row + offset D 2 rows down.

Comment: You are right, the merged cells are automatic and is coming from a website that I consider source for all the data in this table. And yes each person can have multiple rows and it can have more than 3 rows, this is basically just an example, and I really don't have a control for it that's why im working to create a tool to get rid of all these issues.

Comment: And as you said, only the top left cell is the one can be recognized to have the actual value, the rest of merged cells will indicate a value of 0. This can be really a problem because the value that I need is always on the bottom part of the merged cell which is the duration

Comment: This is why I have created a helper column which is the Column F in Table 1. It will try to extract the duration and it will be located in the same row with the agent's name. But I really don't know what I can do more about that helper column to fix my issue.

Comment: I believe I got it. It is filtering out column D unless it includes a `-` or a time value. See updated post.

Comment: Damn you are amazing lol! Sorry for checking this out late. I was too busy myself trying to figure this out lol. Now I am trying to explore the formula and do other things with it. But so far this resolved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Respect. A valuable lesson learned. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

### Filter Data With Merged Cells

**EDIT**

- My sample data was too simple. Added `CleanTimeCol`.

```
=LET(array,A3:D23,
    TimeCol,TAKE(array,,-1),CleanTimeCol,IF(ISNUMBER(TimeCol),TimeCol,"-"),MergeShift,2,
        TimeArray,IFERROR(INDEX(CleanTimeCol,SEQUENCE(ROWS(array),,1+MergeShift)),"-"),
        FilterArray,HSTACK(DROP(array,,-1),TimeArray),
    FirstCol,TAKE(array,,1),
        FilterInclude,FirstCol<>"",
            FILTER(FilterArray,FilterInclude))
```

[image]

**Formula working for the data in this post's screenshot:**

```
=LET(array,A3:D23,
    TimeCol,TAKE(array,,-1),MergeShift,2,
        TimeArray,IFERROR(INDEX(TimeCol,SEQUENCE(ROWS(array),,1+MergeShift)),"-"),
        FilterArray,HSTACK(DROP(array,,-1),TimeArray),
    FirstCol,TAKE(array,,1),
        FilterInclude,FirstCol<>"",
            FILTER(FilterArray,FilterInclude))
```

- `array,A3:D23` - all data
- `TimeCol,TAKE(array,,-1)` - the last (time) column
- `MergeShift,2` - a constant to cover for merged columns
- `TimeArray,IFERROR(INDEX(TimeCol,SEQUENCE(ROWS(array),,1+MergeShift)),"-")` - `SEQUENCE` will produce `3,4,5,...23` (`21` rows), `INDEX` will return errors for rows `20` and `21` (for the numbers `22` and `23`), and `IFERROR` will replace them with dashes
- `FilterArray,HSTACK(DROP(array,,-1),TimeArray)` - stacking the first 3 columns and the time array producing the 1st `FILTER` parameter
- `FirstCol,TAKE(array,,1)` - the first column
- `FilterInclude,FirstCol<>""` - first column non-blanks producing the 2nd `FILTER` parameter
- `FILTER(FilterArray,FilterInclude)` - the `FILTER` formula

Answer (score 0):

**In case of fixed height merge**

```
=LET(merged,A2:F23,
     seq,SEQUENCE(1+MAX(ROW(merged))-MIN(ROW(merged)),,MIN(ROW(merged))),
     condition,DROP(REDUCE(0,seq,LAMBDA(x,y, VSTACK(x,(IFERROR(1/(INDEX(A:A,y)<>"")/(INDEX(A:A,y+1)="")/(INDEX(A:A,y+2)="")+1,0))))),1),
     columnD,INDEX(INDEX(merged,,4),1+ROW(merged)-MIN(ROW(merged))+condition),
     flt,FILTER(HSTACK(TAKE(merged,,3),columnD,TAKE(merged,,-1)),CHOOSECOLS(merged,1)<>""),
IF(flt=0,"",flt))
```

[image]

This first takes the whole range of data including merged cells and names it `merged`.

Then a sequence is created of it's row numbers: `seq`

Then it checks column A row by row as defined in `seq` if that row contains value and the next two rows don't. If so it returns `1`, if not `0`. This array is named `condition` and is used to show the value in column D from 2 rows below if the `condition`-array equals `1` and the current row if the it equals `0`. which results in `columnD`

If we then stack the `merged` range columns prior to the altered `columnD` and the  last `merged` range column and filter out the rows where the first `merged` range column has blank values you get your result: `flt`.
to avoid blank cells to show as `0` I added `IF(flt=0,"",flt)`.

You can choose to include or exclude the header from your data. It works both ways.

**in case of variable height merge**

If the merged cells are not per definition 3 merged rows, the following formula works:

```
=LET(merged,A2:F23,
     r,ROWS(merged),
     s,SEQUENCE(r),
     shiftrow,MAP(s,s+1,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(remainder,INDEX(merged,SEQUENCE(r-a,,b),1),(INDEX(merged,a,1)<>"")*(IFERROR(INDEX(merged,b,1)="",0))*IFERROR(XMATCH("*",remainder,2)-1,IFERROR(ROWS(remainder),0))))),
     d,INDEX(merged,s+shiftrow,4),
     mf,HSTACK(TAKE(merged,,3),d,TAKE(merged,,-1)),
     unmerged,FILTER(mf,TAKE(mf,,1)<>""),
IF(unmerged=0,"",unmerged))
```

[image]

This first takes in the whole range `merged`, then `shiftrow` checks if the cell in the current row `c` contains a value and the value in the next row `n` is blank, it returns the number of rows the next non-blank cell is found from the next row -1 as a value.
If `shiftrow` returns TRUE it checks for the first non-empty cell from the next row `n` to the last row; if `shiftrow` returns FALSE it returns `0`

`d` returns the column D indexed in it's rows (`s` = `sequence(rows(merged)))`) + the `shiftrow` value.

`mf` combines the merged range columns A:C with the fixed values in column D `d` and the last column of the merged range.

`unmerged` filters out the rows with empty values in the first column from `mf`

Finally `0` is replaced with blanks.