# excel - need outcome from multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

| Alphabet | Name | Date | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Sam | 4/23 | blue |
| X(1) | Jay | 2/21 | pink |
| Y | Tim | 1/14 | red |
| Z | Luke | 5/23 | white |

I get this excel file from a website. It has same fields but the data in there can vary from 100 lines to 200 sometimes. I need information on x, y, z from that dataset and information from 4 columns related to them.

I have tried using filter function but it doesn't use the exact match and I end up getting results for X and X(1) when I only want the results for X. I tried using v lookup but then I cant get the information in other columns. Everytime I get this dataset I need the information on Xyz in each set so now I use filter to get the information but I would like to make this process easier. Let me know if there are any other formulas or functions I can look into to make this work.

filter function, and vlookup. Need something that can provide exact value with information from other columns.

Comment: Please share the exact `FILTER` formula you used.

Comment: Why have you tagged `excel-2010` whilst also mentioning your attempt at using a function not available in that version (`FILTER`)?

Comment: So you know what you are looking for in a know structured table and you want to pick informations from those specific rows? Why isn't `VLOOKUP` good? Have you considered using the `MATCH` function combined with the `INDEX` function? Why did you added the tag `python` while you are not mentioning it in the question?

Comment: welcome @user21818031, try my proposed solution below (accept/decline soln as req. for the benefit of future users/members) ta
(notwithstanding - let me know if this doesn't serve your cause, will do best to help you resolve) -- some good tips in earlier comments to be aware of e.g. choice of Tag etc. best of luck with your spreadsheet/exercise!

Comment: Any idea why you need Excel formula when you work with Excel using Python...? The other solution would be to simply create a pivot table in a second sheet using entire sheet of your this raw data. Then pick up whatever filter you need from it. Again, if you are using python, you already limited Excel a raw data source only (.csv, .txt) or output presentation (info table, graphs etc)...

Comment: These questions could be of some help to you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74253833/1389394) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75177322/1389394)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Criteria in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75177322/multiple-criteria-in-filter)

Answer (score 1):

```
=FILTER(A2:D5,(A2:A5="X")+(A2:A5="Y")+(A2:A5="Z"))
```

[image: screenshot : X, Y, Z {exact match, exclusive, case-sensitive}]

---

---

**Alternative**

`match()` could be utilised as follows:

```
=LET(x_,IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A5,{"X","Y","Z"},0),""),FILTER(A2:D5,--(x_<>"")))
```

[image: alternative (match)- screenshot]

*Note: this may be more tractable than the first function above if you have many different values to filter on (more than just the 3 in this example, say) - this is because you can reference cells containing the values in place of {"*`X`"*,"`Y`", ... etc.} whereas this doesn't seem possible with the first function, which would require typing out each of the (`range="exact value"`) entries...*

---

**Customizations | Notes** *(applic. for either/both fns above)*

- Vary range [50-100?]: - consider Table feature or dynamic range as outlined in my soln [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76116383/arrayformula-from-google-sheets-not-working-in-excel/76116651#76116651)).
- Vary values to filter: remove/add additional entries of the form (range = [exact value, e.g. "X", "W" etc.]), e.g. if (only) `Y`, `Z` required, use: `filter(A2:D5,(A2:A5="Y") + (A2:A5="Z"))` - order doesn't matter in this regard
- Note: this will be case-sensitive, also - alphabet field values of the form "`X Y Z`" or "`X Y`" etc. will **not** be returned (even if `X`,`Y` and `Z` are desired) - the cell **must** contain `X`, `Y`, or `Z` (mutually exclusive, i.e. alone)
- Also, per above link - this is an array function - only enter in the leading cell of the contiguous range you wish to populate - such is the nature of filter - you can wrap an index around this for individualised output e.g. `index(filter_fn, [row_num],[col_num])` to return respective rows/columns of the filter_fn result if desired
- *safe to assume you are using Office 365 compatible Excel version - required for this function - given you have made reference to `filter()` function which is not avail. in earlier versions unless using an Office Insider/Beta testing a/c)*